# Как поменять размеры точек монтирования в Ubuntu

Tags: hdd, монтирование, ubuntu

Необходимо уменьшить Точку Монтирования "/home", увеличить "/" и "swap". Желательно сделать это в графическом интерфейсе, чтобы программа сама всё учла.

Comment: ну а разве при установке ubuntu ты не указываешь размеры точкам монтирования?

Comment: вы мне предлагаете систему перестановить? Сохранятся ли при этом данные на ПК? З,Ы, на всякий случай:На сколько мне известно точка монтирования "/home" автоматически не выставляется, следовательно о том что при установке системы можно указывать размер Т.М. мне известно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да берёте и загружаетесь с LiveCD убунты, и запускаете GParted. Уменьшайте и сдвигайте. Если убунты нет, то загрузите Parted Magic, он легковесный. С помощью утилиты unetbootin можно записать этот образ на чистый Flash-диск и сделать его загрузочным. А у RPM-based дистрибутивов LiveCD неприоритетный образ для установки, так что если будете выбирать образ, смотрите чтобы это был LiveCD.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте gparted: [GParted is the Gnome Partition Editor application](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted).

Comment: Ну так скачайте лайв-сд образ с домашней странички проекта [gparted][1].[1]:http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Answer (score 1):

gparted использовать получится только для раздела home и swap, для корня такой фокус не получится, сам себя он не сможет изменить, так как изменения размера раздела происходит при его отмонтировании. Такую операцию можно сделать, если только загрузитесь с Live CD. Сразу хочу предупредить, это очень длительный процесс. Сравним с перестановкой системы. Все зависит от объемов. При переустановке системы укажите, что старый раздел /home форматировать не надо и все данные сохранятся. А вообще-то такие вещи стоит писать по конкретней, указывая увеличивать раздел нужно или уменьшать (последнее сделать проще при незаполненной партиции) на одном они диске или на разных. Нюансов много.